# yii2 widget error

Tags: tinymce, composer-php, yii2

I want download `yii2-tinymce-widget` for yii with this command:

```
$ composer require 2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget:~1.1
```

However, it is not working. The error is:

> The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

Why? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Add in `composer.json` `"minimum-stability": "dev"`

Comment: @vitalik_74   thanks, but not working yet

Comment: This problem cannot be answered without knowing your other dependencies in the composer.json file. Please add it to your question. My best guess now would be that you already include anything that this package has as a dependency in an incompatible version. That means either tinymce/tinymce in a version less than 4, or the Yii framework in a version different from ~2.0.0 (i.e. less than 2 or 2.1.x and up).